# Ошибка при присвоении NULL ассоциативной коллекции: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Tags: oracle, коллекции, plsql

Хочу очистить ассоосиативную коллекцию и присваиваю ей `NULL`:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE arrtype IS TABLE OF INTEGER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    arr arrtype;
BEGIN
    arr := NULL;
END;
/
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Какая причина, и как очистить коллекцию полностью?

А если хочу присвоить `NULL` одному элементу, то как это сделать?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [NULL assigning to associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63411937) от участника [@TBose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13904126/tbose)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63411937

Answer (score 2):

Ассоциативные коллекции - [Associative Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-8060F01F-B53B-48D4-9239-7EA8461C2170), в отличии от других видов коллекций (*nested tables*, *varray*), могут быть пустыми, но не могут быть `NULL`:

> Like a database table, an associative array:
>
> - Is empty (**but not null**) until you populate it

```
declare
    type arrtype is table of integer index by pls_integer;
    arr arrtype;
begin 
    dbms_output.put_line (
        'size='||arr.count||' isnull='||case when arr is null then 'yes' else 'no' end);
end;
/ 

size=0 isnull=no
```

Отдельным элементам ассоциаативной коллекции, может быть присвоено значение `NULL`, но при этом, элемент не будет удалён из коллекции. Для удаления всех (или отдельных) элементов коллекции, надо воспользоваться методом [`DELETE[(N)]`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-E43509F6-5044-4B17-9516-2EB4BDDD5173).

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
declare 
    type arrtype is table of integer index by pls_integer;
    arr arrtype;
    procedure termout (memo varchar2) is
    begin dbms_output.put_line (rpad (memo||':', 16)||
        'size='||arr.count||' isnull='||case when arr is null then 'yes' else 'no' end);
    end;
begin 
    termout ('empty');
    arr := arrtype (1=>999, 2=>NULL);
    termout ('filled');
    arr.delete (2);
    termout ('del one elem.');
    arr.delete;
    termout ('del all elem.');
end;
/

empty:          size=0 isnull=no
filled:         size=2 isnull=no
del one elem.:  size=1 isnull=no
del all elem.:  size=0 isnull=no
```